# Unable to retrieve date input value C# Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, input, datepicker, webforms

[Here is what I can see when I do e.Item.FindControl for the TextBox I'm trying to get the value for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhxlV.png)

I have 2 date inputs in a list view and I am trying to retrieve their values but always get an empty string.

If I set the value in the front end then it comes through to the code behind but if I edit the field the original value is returned.

I am able to get the values from  and  controls without an issue.

I've tried using asp:TextBox and html

```
<asp:TextBox ID="editArrivalFrom" name="editArrivalFrom" TextMode="Date" runat="server" OnTextChanged="editArrivalFrom_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
<input type="date" id="editArrivalTo" name="editArrivalTo" runat="server" />

var arrivalFrom = (TextBox) e.Item.FindControl("editArrivalFrom");
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrivalFrom.Text))

var arrivalTo = (HtmlInputGenericControl) e.Item.FindControl("editArrivalTo");
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arrivalTo.Value))
```

I've also tried using Request.Form, all of the below return null:

```
var test = Request.Form[arrivalFrom.UniqueID];
var test2 = Request.Form[arrivalFrom.ClientID];
var test3 = Request.Form["editArrivalFrom"];
```

There is also no sign of either of the inputs in Request.Form.AllKeys

The asp control doesn't show up in the designer.cs file and adding it only results in it being null anyway.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated I've been pulling my hair out for hours.

Relevant code for the form update is below. Please note that all of this is contained within an update panel

```
<asp:ListView ID="MarkupRuleList" runat="server"
        OnItemCommand="MarkupRuleList_OnItemCommand">
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnUpdate" CssClass="lstview_record_bttn button-spacing-7" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' runat="server" />
</EditItemTemplate

protected void MarkupRuleList_OnItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        int markupId = 0;
        int.TryParse(e.CommandArgument.ToString(), out markupId);
        var markup = new MarkupRuleDTO();

        switch (e.CommandName)
        {
            case "Update":
                // GetMarkupRuleFromPage contains all of the code from the top of this post
                markup = GetMarkupRuleFromPage(e, markupId);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Edit: Solved by ditching the date input and using regular textbox, then performing the following onkeyup JS function

```
function dateInputHandler(item, event) {
    // key code 8 == backspace
    if (event.keyCode != 8) {
        // insert forward slashes after days and months
        if (item.value.length == 2 || item.value.length == 5) {
            item.value = item.value + '/'
        }
        // remove double slashes and prevent length exceeding 10 characters
        // format should be dd/mm/yyyy
        if (item.value.endsWith("//") || item.value.length > 10) {
            item.value = item.value.slice(0, -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your entire page code , for example how you are submitting your page to code behind.

Comment: @GaganDeep Added above

Comment: I really can't understand your code, the is no line in the event of list view where you are accessing the textbox or the input control.. also please specify whether your textbox is inside the template field of the list view or directly placed inside the page.??

Comment: @GaganDeep Clicking the LinkButton (which is within the EditItemTemplate in the ListView) triggers the OnItemCommand method with a command name of "Update". This then calls GetMarkupRuleFromPage which is where the code shown at the top is contained.

Comment: Have you tried to access the textbox directly inside the switch case rather than doing that inside another method.

Comment: @GaganDeep Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried and it didn't work. It's probably worth noting that I can access other inputs (input type="text" & asp:DropDownList) from that method without issue. Changing the problematic inputs to input type="text" allows me to get the value from them directly.

Comment: thats strange though.

Comment: I will try to reproduce the issue when I get to my system tomorrow and will post here.

Comment: @GaganDeep Thanks so much I really appreciate you trying to help out on this one! I'm gonna have another go this evening will update here if I find anything

Comment: Just another query. Does your textbox has autopostback true. And I can see your textbox markup has textchanged event. Are you doing anything in that event?? If not, could you remove that piece of markup.

Comment: @GaganDeep I put in the text changed event to try to see what happened when the text was updated but it wasn't ever triggered. Your comment made me realise that this is because autopostback was set to false.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off casting the sender object rather than the EventArgs object.

```
var x = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
```

But you can access the control directly (or should be able to).

```
var x = editArrivalFrom.Text;
```

And to get from the form, use the correct variable name:

```
var x = Request.Form[editArrivalFrom.ClientID];
```

Comment: Hi Steve, I'm not able to access editArrivalFrom directly as it's not in the designer.cs file and adding it just results in editArrivalFrom == null unless I'm missing something.


    `protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox editArrivalFrom;`

Comment: Shouldn't need to add it in the designer. Adding it to the aspx page should automatically sort that out.

Comment: Yes I agree but it doesn't and I can't figure out why. Perhaps because it's in a ListView EditItemTemplate and therefore not always rendered?

Comment: Also worth noting that in this instance the sender is the ListView, not the TextBox. You can get to the control through the sender but the value is still an empty string regardless of what is shown on the front end.